# When the water flows out, will the outlet at the bottom of the beaker also produce a reaction force?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

[image: Water outflow diagram at the bottom of beaker]

Suppose there is a beaker filled with water, and there is an outlet on its side wall. Under gravity, when water flows out of the beaker outlet, there will be a reaction force at the beaker outlet; If the outlet of the beaker is set on the bottom plane of the beaker, will a reaction force also occur at the outlet of the beaker when water flows out from the bottom outlet of the beaker?

[image: The diameter of the outflow water is reduced]

As shown in the figure, I think the beaker can be regarded as a funnel, that is, a container with large upper part and small lower part. When the water flows out of the outlet at the bottom of the beaker, the diameter of the water shrinks after leaving the outlet section of the beaker (Note: the diameter shrinks not due to falling, but due to the speed direction of the water, which is shown in the figure).According to Bernoulli's theorem, when the diameter of the water flow gradually decreases along the flow direction, the upstream pressure must be higher than the downstream pressure. Therefore, there is a reaction force at the outlet of the beaker.

Comment: Why do you think there willn't be a reaction force?

Comment: If you are working with gauge pressure, the reaction force is zero.

Comment: @DebanjanBiswas Someone told me that there is no reaction force, but I doubt it. I think there is reaction force.

Comment: Why the Down Votes and Votes to Close? This is a perfectly good conceptual question, not a Homework Question.

Comment: @enbin Good question. Could you add to your Question your reason(s) for thinking there is a reaction force? An explanation of your confusion might stop further votes to close the question, and also help those who are answering to provide a more focussed answer. ... Are you assuming that the fluid (water) is ideal?

Comment: @sammygerbil I have added my thoughts.

Comment: @enbin Thanks. But you appear to have left out a step in your explanation. You say that the diameter of the water shrinks, and then say "Therefore there is a reaction force at the outlet." Why does the diameter shrinking mean that there is a reaction force?

Comment: @sammygerbil According to Bernoulli's theorem, when the diameter of the water flow gradually decreases along the flow direction, the upstream pressure must be higher than the downstream pressure.